# Altium - handling multiple net names for buses

Tags: altium, wire, bus

I'm confused on how to solve this warning on Altium.

```
Nets Element[1]: RELAY has multiple names (Net Label Relay1,Net Label Relay1,Net Label RELAY1 (Inferred),Sheet Entry R1-IN(Input))

Nets Element[1]: Relay has multiple names (Sheet Entry R1-IN(Input),Net Label RELAY1 (Inferred),Net Label Relay1,Net Label Relay1)
```

And so on for the whole bus. I have solved similar warnings for other single lines by using **Net Ties**, but that is not working for this case. Altium ends up giving an error that "**The respective nets are unconnected**".

There has to be a standard way of solving this issue.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you route the bus to the input port, instead of a wire with the same name as the bus?

Comment: All the 8 repititions get the whole bus. Which is wrong for my design. I need to send only one Signal (RelayN - where N is repition number) to each of the repitions.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.altium.com/documentation/1.0/display/NEXUS/WorkspaceManager_Err-NetsWithMultipleNames((Nets+with+Multiple+Names))_AD) you can find how to solve your problem (Altium Website)

The problem you are describing / the error message can be corrected by ensuring that the names of all IDs are the same.

You can also ensure that you can go about your business freely, so you must do the following:

Set the report mode for this error to no report on the error reporting tab or the project options dialog box. You can find this at project -> project options

Comment: Like I said, this resolution works for single wires case. This is not a simple case. I have 8 different nets each going to 8 different copies of the same board. Its not possible to name them accordingly such that it matches.

Comment: If you know a way, glad to hear about it. Keep in mind this is 8 net bus going into a sheet symbol repeated 8 times. @Joost

Comment: Sorry, It's more complex than I thought. Maybe you can find it [here](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/((Multi-Sheet+and+Multi-Channel+Design))_AD).

Comment: I already have studied the resources you are mentioning. In fact that is the first thing which Google gives out. If you have any other ideas, I'll be happy to discuss.

Comment: @Mohsin maybe you can ask your question at the Altium Forum [here](https://live.altium.com/signin?prmGotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.live.altium.com%2F).